# How to eliminate millisecond of blank page before page loads

Tags: html, css, flicker

On some sites I create, when navigating from page to page, there is a millisecond of totally white blank page before the normal page loads up. I used to think this had to do with caching issues. Recently I coded [a site](http://jmc-creative.com/web/krackm/ccfarm) (still in testing) which has virtually no php, javascript or anything fancy. It's essentially just straight html & css, and very sparsely written. There is also a .htaccess requiring cache of all js, css, img, etc. The page itself loads very fast.

Some sites seem to have this white flicker or flash of nothing in between pages. Other site don't. I've never been able to figure out what it is. Chrome & Firefox both exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accidentally had a call for a nonexistant js file in the head (leftover from a template). The millisecond of white blankness was the  server trying to get the file, looking for it, and not finding it. :(

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if the browser needs to download a lot of data (such as Javascript) before it can start rendering anything.

Move all scripts to the end of the body so that the browser doesn't need to wait for them to download and execute before rendering your content.

Minify all of your CSS so that it takes less time to download.

Comment: Yes I would moving the javascript to the bottom.

Comment: I agree this is a good idea. But in this case, my css is 5k. I seriously doubt this would make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

As I see "jquery-ui-min.js" is a quite large (about 242 kbyte minified) script file, so I moved it into a loader script. If you have other "big" scripts, you have to load them later as well. But don't forget to move those initializer scripts too, which call these scripts, to avoid calling a "non-existing yet" function!
Of course, the first script is the latest jquery.js.

```
function load_scripts(){
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js";
    $("head").append(s);
}
```